# How do i redirect my all old url to new url Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I want to redirect my all old url to new url.

My few old URLs are

domain.com/
domain.com/submit
domain.com/get/soft-name
domain.com/most-downloaded

etc, etc,

Now i want to redirect my all url to

domain.com/en
domain.com/en/submit
domain.com/en/get/soft-name
domain.com/en/most-downloaded

I am using CodeIgniter. Please Suggest me some code for route.php

thanks in advance

Comment: It might help if you would show us some of your approaches and not just ask for a solution for you to copy+paste.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle this in your routing, you could just do this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "en/$1";
```